# Is it possible using a vscode extension to get info on which regions are folded in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, folding

I would like to find a way to get the folded regions in the active editor using a custom extension.

I have done a lot of researches, but I didn't find anything on this subject.

Also, I tried to query the state.vscdb of the workspace, but I am not getting consistent results, as I think, VS Code is keeping this db in memory and I am not sur when it is updating it on disk.